# Shuffling tfrecords files

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have 5 tfrecords files, one for each object. While training I want to  read data equally from all the 5 tfrecords i.e. if my batch size is 50, I should get 10 samples from 1st tfrecord file, 10 samples from the second tfrecord file and so on. Currently, it just reads sequentially from all the three files i.e. I get 50 samples from the same record. Is there a way to sample from differnt tfrecords files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I advise you to read the [tutorial](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/16kHNtQslt-yuJ3w8GIx-eEH6t_AvFeQOchqGRFpAD7U/edit#slide=id.g254d08e080_0_370) by @mrry on `tf.data`. On slide 42 he explains how to use [`tf.data.Dataset.interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) to read multiple tfrecord files at the same time.

For instance if you have 5 files, containing:

```
file0.tfrecord: [0, 1]
file1.tfrecord: [2, 3]
file2.tfrecord: [4, 5]
file3.tfrecord: [6, 7]
file4.tfrecord: [8, 9]
```

You can write the dataset like this:

```py
files = ["file{}.tfrecord".format(i) for i in range(5)]
files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
dataset = files.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x),
                           cycle_length=5, block_length=1)

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)  # parse the record
```

The parameters of `interleave` are:
- `cycle_length`: number of files to read concurrently. If you want to read from all your files to create a batch, set this to the number of files (in your case this is what you should do since each file contains one type of label)
- `block_length`: each time we read from a file, reads `block_length` elements from this file

We can test that it works as expected:

```py
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(num_samples):
        print(sess.run(x))
```

which will print:

```
0
2
4
6
8
1
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: That's a very cool presentation you've linked there. What is the source of it? Are there more such presentations by tf authors?

Comment: @3voC: the source Derek Murray (mrry) who is working in the TensorFlow team and who created the tf.data API.

Comment: Make sure the filename pattern that you provide to `tf.data.Dataset.list_files()` is exact. I provided `path/to/train//*.tfrecords` and it failed. (Note the double slash)